# What happened to "allow application to interact with desktop" checkbox in cluster manager for server 2008?

Tags: windows-server-2008, cluster-computing, failovercluster

The cluster managing software for managing clusters on a windows server 2005 cluster had a checkbox for "allow application to interact with desktop" when creating a generic application resource.  This appears to be gone in the management software for server 2008 clusters.  Does anyone know where this option, if it still exists, is?

Comment: actually, would this be better asked on serverfault?  If so, how can I move it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [MattB](https://serverfault.com/users/4491/mattb) on ServerFault, got [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/126598/what-happened-to-allow-application-to-interact-with-desktop-checkbox-in-cluster) response.

> This option was removed in Server 2008 as a security enhancement. This is because the application runs as the cluster service account which has elevated privileges.
>
> Even in 2003 clusters, the security best practice was to not have this checked.